# Can my ant task wait for JBoss to deploy

Tags: java, deployment, ant, jboss

With a quick scan on the net and the forums I find that link http://www.mail-archive.com/jboss-user@lists.sourceforge.net/msg22511.html :

> Use ant's  task to hit the jmx-console. The URL should look like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor?action=invokeOpByName&name=jboss.system:service%3DMainDeployer&methodName=deploy&argType=java.lang.String&arg=${deploy.target}
```

but when i try to use it ant build faild saying "The reference to entity "name" must end with the ';' delimiter." 
Is there a way to deploy a package to the jboss and wait until deployment is finished.
I am open to any solution even without Ant.
Thanks in advance for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you quote indicates bad XML.  You're embedding a URL in the Ant buildfile that contains ampersands:

```
http:// ... /jmx-console/ ... &name=jboss.system:service ...
```

In XML that `&name` looks like an unterminated entity - the message says Ant thinks you should add a semicolon to terminate - `&name;` - so you've confused it!

You could use the ampersand XML entity `&amp;` in place of the raw `&`s:

```
<get url="http:// ... /jmx-console/ ... &amp;name=jboss.system:service ..." ... />
```

Or maybe set the URL in CDATA for an Ant property, and then use that in the get task.

```
<property name="url"><![CDATA[http://raw_url_here]]></property>
<get src="${url}" ... />
```